# Proving that if $f$ is continuous then $f(a_n)$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Prove that if $$(a_n)=\left(\frac{n(1+\cos(\pi n))}{2 n+1}\right)$$

then the sequence $(f(a_n))$ converges.

I noticed that $a_n$ goes back and forward from $0$ to $1$ for all $n>0$. I tried playing with the intermediate value theorem but with no luck. What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $f(a_n)$ converges if and only if $f(a_{2n})$ and $f(a_{2n+1})$ converge to the **same** limit.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but is true that if $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ then $f$ is constant on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @trfv Let $a \in [0,1)$. Then $f(a)=f(a^{2^n})$. If $f$ is continuous, then it follows that  $f(a)=\lim_n f(a^{2^n})=f(\lim_n a^{2^n})=f(0)$. This shows that $f$ is constant on $[0,1)$ and by continuity it is constant on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @trfv If $f$ is not continuous, this is not true.

Comment: Great, exactly what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: @N.S. and trfv - "and by continuity it is constant on $[0,1]$" - you mean because $f(0)=f(1)$?

Comment: @Kmt I was answering the question in the comment which is a completely different question. In that question we don't know that $f(0)=f(1)$....

Comment: @N.S. - actually, I meant the same conditions as in the question of the OP (including $f(0)=f(1)$) excluding the sequence thing. I also thought that you deduced $f$ being constant on $[0,1]$ from the fact that $f(0)=f(1)$ (because you showed that in $[0,1)$, $f=f(0)$ and because $f(0)=f(1)$ it is also constant in $[0,1]$).

Comment: @trfv You don't even need the $f(0)=f(1)$ condition. Once you prove that $f(x)$ is constant on $[0,1)$, you just take $x_n \in [0,1)$ which converge to $1$ and use $f(1)=\lim_n f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$ so:

$$a_n=0 $$  if $n$ is odd,
$$a_n=\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$   if $n$ is even,

Therefor $a_n$ has two partial limits: $0$ and $1$.

No matter where $a_n$ converges to $0$ or $1$. $f(a_n$) always converges to unique limit since $f(0)=f(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $(a_n)$ converges on the circle, then since $f$ is continuous on the circle you will be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I think that what should be retained from this exercise was not mentioned.

It is known that if $f$ is continuous on a set, say $I=[0,1],$ then for any
sequence $(a_{n})$ of points of $I,$ one has%
\begin{equation*}
\text{if}\ (a_{n})\text{ converges to some }a\in I,\ \text{then}\ f(a_{n})\ 
\text{converges}\ \text{to}\ f(a).
\end{equation*}
This exercise teach us that the converse is not true and provides an
'extreme' couterexample! in the sense
that one has 
\begin{equation*}
f(a_{n})\ converges\ to\ f(0)=f(1)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
but\ \ the\ sequence\  (a_{n})\ not\ only\ do\ not\ converges\ to\ 0\ nor\ to\
1,\ but\ it\ diverges\ at\ all.
\end{equation*}